# Logical Explanation to the below c/c++ solution

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math, geometry

Can someone please explain to me why is GCD used in the following Solution:

http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/2849602 (for c)

http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/2849324 (for c++)

for the question: http://www.codechef.com/ACMKAN13/problems/LINEPROB

A Sniper is standing at the point (x1, y1) on the 2D XY Plane. He shoots from his position towards the point (x2, y2). You may assume that all points are integers.

Consider the 2D grid formed by integer points on the XY Plane. The position of the Sniper and the Target are lattice points in this grid. The bullet shot by the Sniper will follow a straight line trajectory from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2). The bullet goes no further than (x2, y2).

Consider the trajectory of the bullet when the Sniper is standing at (1, 1) and the Target lies at (4, 3).

[image]

Notice how the trajectory of the bullet touches 4 cells. A cell is considered touched by the trajectory if and only if the bullet will enter the cell. How many cells are touched by the trajectory of the bullet?

￼
Input

The first line contains a single integer T, the number of test cases. Each of the following T lines contain one test case each. Each test case contains 4 integers x1, y1, x2 and y2. The integers are separated by single space characters.
Output

For each test case, output a single line, containing the number of cells touched by the trajectory of the bullet shot from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2). Remember that a cell is considered touched by the trejectory if and only if the bullet enters the cell - only touching a side is not enough.
Constraints

0 < T < 10100
0 ≤ x1, y1, x2, y2 ≤ 1000000000

Sample Input

3
0 0 3 2
0 0 2 2
0 0 1 0

Sample Output

4
2
0

Comment: Yes, it has ended, But I just wanted to know the logic behind using GCD. I actually liked the solution but couldnot come up with a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic behind the solution is:

> number of blocks the bullet traverses going along the X-axis, plus
>   number of blocks the bullet traverses going along the Y-axis, minus
>   number of blocks that got over-counted

Given the points `(X1, Y1)` and `(X2, Y2)`, let `A1 = abs(X1 - X2)` and `A2 = abs(Y1 - Y2)`. Then, without loss of generality, we can consider the points `(0, 0)` and `(A1, A2)`.

Notice that `A1` represents the number of blocks the bullet traverses along the X-axis. But, this is also the number of vertical lines touched by the bullet on the interval `(0, A1]` on the grid. Similarly, `A2` represents the number of blocks the bullet traverses along the Y-axis, and also the number of horizontal lines touched by the bullet on the interval `(0, A2]`.

When viewed as the number of touched lines, it is easier to see why you need to subtract some number. The number that needs to be subtracted is the number that corresponds to the touches that occur at the intersections of vertical and horizontal lines. The number of occurrences of that are counted by the GCD of `A1` and `A2`. In particular, it occurs at the points `(k * A1/GCD(A1,A2), k * A2/GCD(A1,A2))` for `k` in `1 .. GCD(A1,A2)`.

Comment: Could you please explain the last part where the intersection are also same as the gcd of the numbers.

Comment: @user1675947: I think I explained that in my last sentence. What do you find unclear in particular?

Comment: Why is the intersection of lines also equal to gcd of numbers?

Comment: The last sentence explains why. The GCD divides evenly into both `A1` and `A2`. So, the intersection points happen every `A1/GCD` to the right, and `A2/GCD` up.

Answer (score 0):

*Before explaining the logic behind using `gcd` I want to clarify that this may not be the exact way the author of this code had thought.*
First, I do not see any use of `max` function in that code.
Explanation:
Let's assume that the

1. sniper is at `(0,0)` and the target is at `(3,3)`. It is clear that the trajectory of bullet will touch `2` cells.
   **Remarks:** When sniper and target is on the line `x = y` or parallel to it, cells touched are one less than that of ordinate (or abscissa). (*This is equal to the sum of the `x` and `y` component of distance traveled by the bullet and subtracting the GCD of the `x` and `y` component of distance traveled by the bullet*.)
2. sniper is at `(0,0)` and the target is at `(0,3)` or `(3,0)`. Again it is clear, by seeing the picture, that the trajectory of bullet will touch `0` cells.
   **Remarks:** When sniper and target is on the line `x` or `y` or parallel to `x` or `y`, cells touched are one `0`. (*This is equal to the sum of the `x` and `y` component of distance traveled by the bullet and subtracting the GCD of the `x` and `y` component of distance traveled by the bullet*.)
3. sniper is at `(1,1)` and the target is at `(4,3)`. It is clear that the trajectory of bullet will touch `4` cells.
   **Remarks:** In all other cases, number of cells are equal to the sum of the `x` and `y` component of distance traveled by the bullet and subtracting the GCD of the `x` and `y` component of distance traveled by the bullet.